# Returning Number of Items in Section iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Very straight forward question here;  I'm using a `UICollectionView` and looking to display a certain number of images per section determined by a count of the images that match the section.

For example:

`Category: x`
`# Images in Category: y`
`# Images In Section: y`

I've got sorting everything into the categories down, and I can get the count for each category, but I'm not sure how to return the correct value for each image in the "Category" section.  This is what I've got so far:

```
- (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Category Delineater Here

for (int i = 0; i <= _categoryCount.count; i++)
{
    PFQuery *tiredQuery = [[PFQuery alloc] initWithClassName:@"savedImages"];
    [tiredQuery whereKey:@"imageCategory" equalTo:[_categoryCount objectAtIndex:0]];
    [tiredQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            NSLog(@"What does this return? %@", objects);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"This returns an error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
}

return _extractedImagesArray.count;
}
```

Currently, `_extractedImagesArray.count` is the total number of images that are downloaded.  How to I change the amount returned in this section based on the number of images a particular category has?

EDIT: For Clarification of data structure:

Each image has a category affixed to it.  The images are all placed in the same Class on Parse.

My ultimate goal is to get it to look similar to this ([x] representing an image in this case):

Category 1
X X X X X

Category 2
X X X

Category 3
X X X X

etc etc

Answer (score 0):

This line looks like a problem:

> `[tiredQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)`

The method you're using runs asynchronously, so you're not going to get the results back right away. `-collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` isn't going wait around for you to find the objects asynchronously and then count them -- you need to return the number of objects immediately.

It sounds like you'll probably need to do some processing ahead of time to determine the number of objects in each section, and then remember the counts somewhere so that you can provide them when asked by the collection view.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Parse.

You should not make a call to the backend while reloading data.  Try something like this:

```
- (void)getImages {
    for (int i = 0; i <= _categoryCount.count; i++) {
        PFQuery *tiredQuery = [[PFQuery alloc] initWithClassName:@"savedImages"];
        [tiredQuery whereKey:@"imageCategory" equalTo:[_categoryCount objectAtIndex:0]];
        [tiredQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 _extractedImagesArray = objects;
                 [collectionView reloadData];
             }
             else {
                 NSLog(@"This returns an error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
             }
         }];
    }
}

- (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _extractedImagesArray.count;
}
```

Here is an example of returning different amounts of items dependent no which section you are referencing.  Remember, section 0 is always the first one.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return xNumber;
            break;
        case 1:
            return yNumber;
            break;
        case 2:
            return zNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to adjust the _extractedImagesArray = objects part of the code depending on how exactly you need to parse your data.

Comment: Adding `getImages` in a different function and allotting it properly only returns the amount of images in the first section.  In this case, it's returning `4` images, and applying that to each section.  How do I make sure that Section 1 has 4 images, Section 2 has 5 images, and Section 3 etc?

Comment: Can you explain to me how Section 1 and Section 2 work on your Parse db?  Do they have a key for it some something?

Comment: No, the images are all in the same class, but they have different "Categories". I've written code to separate the images into the unique categories, which is logging out properly, but there's no deviation other then that.

Comment: Are you already using section 0 for something in the collection view?  You could just put in an if stamens with a return in it.  I'll add a quick example above.

Comment: Whoops, I apologize for that.  In this case I'm referring to 0 in the array when I say section 1.  My apologies.

Comment: The issue with the answer you have above is that technically I don't know how many categories there are going to be.  Could be 5, 2, 20 or anywhere in between.

Comment: In that case, the last thing you should need to do is get the number of items for each section, put it into an array when you retrieve the data from Parse, and then read the number of items for each section in the collectionView delegate method.

Comment: How would I go about executing that?

Comment: That is getting out of the scope of this question.  If you need help with that  Try doing some research on NSMutableArray, look at other posts on StackOverflow, or post a new question.  But before you do, please mark the answer above and answered, or do not mark it answered if you do not feel like it was appropriate.  Good luck!